# I am having trouble parsing a nested JSON array for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, json

I have a a JSON obj that I am parsing into a , but the nested values are not being accessed for the second level .

if the first selector has only one detail value, like "Person to Person" or "Search Engine" then it doesn't display the second selctor but sets a variable to the value of it's only key. for example, if I select "person to Person", then it sets a variable value ANS to "50000001" if I select "Radio", the next selector appears and if I select "Comedy" it sets variable ANS to 10000001.

I created a CodePen for this: https://codepen.io/SimplyMarkB/pen/PoqpBEZ

```
let sources = [{
    "Radio" : {
        "Comedy" : "10000001",
        "News" : "10000002",
        "Music" : "10000003",
        "Talk" : "10000004",
        "Entertainment" : "10000005",
        "Religious" : "10000006"
    },
    "Direct Mail" : {
        "Direct Mail" : "30000001"
    },
    "Search Engine" : {
        "Search Engine" : "20000001"
    },
    "Person to Person" : {
        "Local Bars" : "50000001"
    }
}]

var media = "";
var ANS = "";

sources.forEach(obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    $("#categoryType").append("<option class='rsource' value='"+key+"'>"+key+"</option>");
  });
});

$("#categoryType").change(function(){
  $("#itemsources").show()
  var selValue = $(this).val();
  // some obj filter based on selValue and populate the select with a value & key
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your change function.
You can see updated codepen also:
https://codepen.io/harshbaba/pen/wvaJYMR

```
 $("#categoryType").change(function(){
   $("#itemsources").show();
   $("#itemsource").empty();
   $("#itemsource").append("<option>Select Detail</option>");
   var selValue = $(this).val();
   var data = sources[0][selValue];
   for(item in data){
    $("#itemsource").append("<option class='isource' value='"+item+"'>"+item+"   
    </option>");
   }
 });
```